# Outputting variable from one thread to other

Tags: python, python-multithreading, infinite-loop

I have a thread that has an infinite loop running, updating a variable constantly. How can I access the live value of that variable in an another thread/outside of the thread (without being in an infinite loop)?

Comment: what do you want to do when you access that variable? threads share the same memory so the easiest is to just make that variable a `global`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the best way to do it is to use global variables.
But, you need to be aware of the lock conditions when threads are reading and writing to one variable at once.

[There is a good manual for example.](https://www.pythonforthelab.com/blog/handling-and-sharing-data-between-threads/)